# Oracle SQL - Concat + Listagg + Count does not work together

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, listagg

I have a table 'allorders' which looks like that:

| Order_Nr | Items |
| --- | --- |
| O100 | 5X1 |
| O100 | 5X1 |
| O100 | 7B3 |
| O101 | 3A2 |
| O101 | 3A2 |

And i would like to get all items from one order as one string + the order number which should look like that:

| Order_Nr | OrderOverview |
| --- | --- |
| O100 | 2 x 5X1 1 x 7B3 |

My SQL-Query looks like that:

```
SELECT Order_Nr, LISTAGG(CONCAT(CONCAT(COUNT(Items), ' x '), Items), ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by Items) as OrderOverview
FROM allorders 
WHERE Order_Nr = 'O100'
ORDER BY Order_Nr;
```

I am using Oracle 11g and I get the following error message:

> ORA-00937: no groupfunction for single-group
> 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

If i don't select the Order_Nr in the SQL Query it works but i would like to see it in the result for a possible view which i would like to create in the future.

What am I missing? Does my idea not work in general?
I hope I have worked up the data okayish, should nevertheless information be missing let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `GROUP BY` twice; first, find the `COUNT` for each item and order pairing and then, second, concatenate the strings with `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT order_nr,
       LISTAGG(counted_items, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY items)
         AS OrderOverview
FROM   (
  SELECT order_nr,
         items,
         COUNT(*) || ' x ' || Items AS counted_items
  FROM   allorders
  WHERE Order_Nr = 'O100'
  GROUP BY
         order_nr,
         items
)
GROUP BY
       order_nr
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE allorders (Order_Nr, Items) AS
SELECT 'O100', '5X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O100', '5X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O100', '7B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O101', '3A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O101', '3A2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ORDER_NR | ORDEROVERVIEW |
> | --- | --- |
> | O100 | 2 x 5X1 1 x 7B3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d9548db2437bb83455275d37255a48d)*

Comment: That was quick... Thank you so much! :)

Comment: There is no need for sub-query

Answer (score 1):

Oracle actually has a unique capability of executing nested aggregate functions

```
select   max(Order_Nr) as Order_Nr
        ,listagg(count(*) || 'x' || Items, ' ') within group (order by Items) as OrderOverview
from     allorders 
where    Order_Nr = 'O100'
group by Items, Order_Nr
```

| ORDER_NR | ORDEROVERVIEW |
| --- | --- |
| O100 | 2x5X1 1x7B3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af6c7521081927fe3a7439c958c0a1e3)

Comment: As i mentioned "If i don't select the Order_Nr in the SQL Query it works but i would like to see it in the result for a possible view which i would like to create in the future."

Comment: If you filter it hard-coded you can also select it hard-coded. Anyways, it's not an issue. Wait 30 seconds.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: P.S. nested aggregate function needs a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas. I have simplified my problem a bit for the question. I probably should have left out the hard-coded WHERE.